# Combine Two regular expression into one

Tags: php, regex

I want to combine two regular expressions in to one.

```
$exp1 =/<area.*?href="([^"]*)".*?[^>]*>/s;
$exp2=/<a.*?href="([^"]*)".*?[^>]*>/s';
```

Comment: Combine how? Should a string match either of them or both of them?

Comment: Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML

Comment: What have you red? What have you done before post question? Before post question, about annoying regular expressions, please, read about regular languages, grammatics, search in google and stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would seriously consider using a proper HTML parser before even touching these kinds of expressions.

That said, what you're after is probably this:

```
/<(?:a|area).*?href="([^"]*)".*?[^>]*>/s
```

The `(?:a|area)` expression is an alternation between `a` and `area`; it's wrapped inside `(?: ... )` to group the alternation *and* treat it as a non-capturing subpattern.

See also: [subpatterns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php), [alternation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.alternation.php)

Comment: Actually, if you're using regex for this, you should at least use word boundaries. Otherwise, you don't need the `area` alternation at all since `a.*?` will also match `area`: `/<(?:a|area)\b.*?href="([^"]*)".*?[^>]*>/s`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it:

```
$exp =/<(?:area|a).*?href="([^"]*)".*?[^>]*>/s;
```

Btw, it's a bad idea to attempt to [parse [X]HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1048572).